# The right connection string for Remote SQL server for C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, remote-server

I just want to know the right sql connection string for a remote sql server express edition.

This is what I got but I got some problems

```
 SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(IP Address)\PC-NAME\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password");
```

I got this error in my C# debugger:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your comment:

> The IP address is the static IP address. I am trying to connect outside the building.

If the database you are trying to connect to is on a computer behind a [router/firewall/modem] that has the target address, you will need to use port forwarding on the [router/firewall/modem] to forward all connections on TCP port 1433 through to the target machine.

If you are trying to connect to a home computer behind an ADSL modem with a static IP address, your ADSL modem needs to be configured with port forwarding to connect the external port 1433 with the same port on the internal address.  This ***must*** be done on the modem, and ***cannot*** be done just with a connection string.

Let's say you have an ADSL modem listening on 127.2.3.4 (invalid address for demonstration only) and a PC behind that with an IP address of 192.168.0.100.  Configure the modem to forward port 1433 to `192.168.0.100:1433` (how will depend on make and model of modem).  Then your connection string would be:

```
Data Source=127.2.3.4\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password
```

Assuming that `SQLEXPRESS` is the only database instance on the server, and since port 1433 is the default, you could use the simpler:

```
Data Source=tcp:127.2.3.4;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password
```

The `Network Library=DBMSSOCN` specification is replaced with `tcp:` and defaults are assumed for instance and port.

Comment: Mind if I ask what happened to the 192.168.0.100 IP Address?? I don't see that within the connection string. Thanks

Comment: @Danny The actual server address needs to be set in the port forwarding on the modem/router.  The connection string tells the SQL client to connect to the modem, which then forwards the connection to the internal server.  From the client's perspective the server is at the public address, not the private address.

Comment: @Corey What if I'm connecting to a VM in Azure, where SQL Server is installed, and remote access is allowed??? in this case, can I put IP address if VM in Data Source???

Comment: @NiravMadariya As long as you can connect to the appropriate TCP port from wherever your clients will be, then sure.  If your Azure VM doesn't have a routable address then you're going to have to find a way to get to it.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution  :** if you are providing remote machine `IP address` then you don't need to provide `hostname`

Try This:

```
SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(IP Address)\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=dbase;User ID=sa;Password=password");
```

Comment: Hi Sir @Sudhakar thanks for the response. The IP address is the static IP address. I am trying to connect outside the building. So Should I specify the computer name for this?

Comment: @LucasJuan: you dont need to provide hostname IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try SqlConnection String Builder [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).